# How to extract Facebook page URL from HTML <a> tag using Regex in Python?

Tags: python, html, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some websites to extract the Facebook page URLs in Python 3 using Beautiful Soup. I am interested to extract only one URL for each website and that redirects into a Facebook page profile and that is not a share-type one.

For this reason I am attempting to use regular expression to extract the URLs from the `href` attribute in `<a>` tags. With Beautiful Soup I extract the first `<a>` tag for each website, filtering by value of the `href` attribute that contains a Facebook page URL.

My code is the following:

```py
# coding=utf-8
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re


def makeSoup(website):
    if 'http' in website:
        page = requests.get(website)
    else:
        page = requests.get('http://' + website)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
    page.close()
    return soup


def facebookProfileScraper(soup):
    link = soup.find('a', {'href': re.compile("https?://(www\\.)?facebook\\.com/[^(share)]?(\\w+\\.?)+")})
    if link is None:
        return "NaN"
    return link['href']
```

Examples of the `<a>` tags from which I'd like to extract the URLs are the following (I put numbers to identify each website also for the results I had with my attempts):

```html
1. <a class="rss fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/gironafc" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
2. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/waterworld.parcaquatic" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
3. <a class="social facebook" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/aquabrava"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
4. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/UEO1921" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="http://www.ueolot.com/wp-content/themes/realsoccer/images/light/social-icon/facebook.png" width="32"/>
</a>
5. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Roc%C3%B2drom-Girona-187271461378780/">Facebook</a>
6. <a class="fb_share" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Skydive-Empuriabrava/44214266003?fref=ts" target="_blank"></a>
```

### First attempt

```regex
https?://(www\\.)?facebook\\.com/[^(share)]?(\\w+\\.?)+
```

But I got these `</a>` tags:

```html
1. <a href="http://facebook.com/share.php?src=bm&amp;v=3&amp;u=" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
2. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/waterworld.parcaquatic" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
3. <a class="social facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/aquabrava" target="_blank"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span></a>
4. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/UEO1921" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="http://www.ueolot.com/wp-content/themes/realsoccer/images/light/social-icon/facebook.png" width="32"/>
</a>
5. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Roc%C3%B2drom-Girona-187271461378780/">Facebook</a>
6. <a class="fb_share" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Skydive-Empuriabrava/44214266003?fref=ts" target="_blank"></a>
```

From website 1. I get the wrong `<a>` tag.

### Second attempt

```regex
https?://(www\\.)?facebook\\.com/[^(share)](\\w+\\.?)+
```

I tried removing the `?` after `[^share]` but I got the following tags:

```html
1. <a class="rss fb" href="http://www.facebook.com/gironafc" target="_blank">Facebook</a>
2. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/waterworld.parcaquatic" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
3. None
4. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/UEO1921" target="_blank"><img alt="Facebook" height="32" src="http://www.ueolot.com/wp-content/themes/realsoccer/images/light/social-icon/facebook.png" width="32"/>
</a>
5. <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Roc%C3%B2drom-Girona-187271461378780/">Facebook</a>
6.<a class="fb_share" href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/Skydive-Empuriabrava/44214266003?fref=ts" target="_blank"></a>
```

From website 3. I don't extract any `<a>` tag because by `[^(share)]` I am negating any url with `a` (or any of `s`, `h`, `r`,`e`) after `http://www.facebook.com/`.

### Third attempt

```regex
https?://(www\\.)?facebook\\.com/(\\w+\\.?)+
```

I tried removing `[^share]` but the tags I got were the same of the first attempt, therefore getting share type URL too.

How can I select only the `a` tags that they don't have a share-type Facebook URL as `href` value?

Comment: So you want to extract urls from a Facebook page which does not have share in it right?

Comment: exactly! I edit the text so it gets more clear

Answer (score 3):

```py
def foo(url):
    l = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "html.parser")
    links = soup.find_all("a")
    for link in links:
        if not "share" in link.get("href").lower():
            l.append(link)
    return l
```

This function checks for `share` in links and return links without `share` in it.

Comment: thank you! The solution works but I would prefer a solution for the regex to have a better performance of my code :)

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution by improving the regex. 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-a-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word) question helped me a lot.
Here's the regex for my case:

```
https?://(www\.)?facebook\.com/(?!share\.php).(\S+\.?)+
```

It matches all of the `<a>` tags with a Facebook page URL as `href` value.

With the regex `(?!anywordorexpression).` it will not be extracted any string containing the `anywordorexpression` substring.

Answer (score 1):

You can use more efficient css attribute selectors with :not and * contains operator using bs4 4.7.1

```
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select("[href^='https://www.facebook.com/']:not([href*='share'])")]
```

For the first link only

```
link = soup.select_one("[href^='https://www.facebook.com/']:not([href*='share'])")['href']
```